# cut a string after a dot in R

Tags: r, character

All my column names start with

```
A.ABC.test1
A.ABC.test2
A.ABC.test3
A.ABC.test4
A.ABC.test5
```

I would like to keep only `test1` , `test2` ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `stringr::str_extract(x,"(?<=\\.)[^\\.]+$")`.

Comment: `sub("......", "", x)` or better `sub(".*\\.", "", x)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: regEx read about regEx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply do: (by chance the same as @jogo commented)

```
colNames <- c("A.ABC.test1","A.ABC.test2","A.ABC.test3","A.ABC.test4","A.ABC.test5")
sub(".*\\.","",colNames)

#[1] "test1" "test2" "test3" "test4" "test5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just       `gsub("A.ABC.", "", x)`

Answer (score 0):

```
x<-as.vector(colnames(df))
colnames(df)<-substr(x,7,11)
```

Where `df` is your data frame.